# Add the quantilies to each line, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, quantile

I am trying to shade the 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles on this graph that has three lines. I have tried geom_area, geom_ribbon, and I cannot highlight every quantile in every line.

Please note that "y" was ignored in this density graph.

```
example <-data.frame(source=c("Leaflitter","Leaflitter","Leaflitter","Leaflitter", 
"Leaflitter","Leaflitter","Leaflitter","Leaflitter","Leaflitter","Leaflitter",
"Biofilm","Biofilm","Biofilm","Biofilm","Biofilm","Biofilm","Biofilm","Biofilm",
"Biofilm","Biofilm","Algae","Algae","Algae","Algae","Algae","Algae","Algae","Algae",
"Algae","Algae"), n=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
density=c(0.554786934, 0.650578421, 0.039317168, 0.53537613,0.435081982,0.904056941,0.556284164,0.855319434,
0.399169622,0.570246304,0.076722032,0.257427999,0.172736928,0.447424473,0.520976948,0.011720494,0.311348655,
         0.120698996,0.016336661,0.331741377,  0.368491034,0.09199358,0.787945904,0.017199397,0.04394107,
0.084222564,0.132367181,0.023981569,0.584493716,0.098012319))

example
```

One subgroup and quantiles

```
L <- filter(QPA_G_Feb17, source == "Leaflitter")
L <-as.data.frame(L)

Lq025  <- quantile(L$density, .025)
Lq975  <- quantile(L$density, .975)
```

```
ggplot(QPA_G_Feb17, aes(x=density, color=source)) + 
  labs(y="Density", x="Sorce contribution") +
  geom_density(aes(linetype = source), size=1.2) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#31a354", "#2c7fb8", "#d95f0e")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dotted", "longdash")) +
  theme_classic()+
  ylim(0, 5)+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(angle=0, size=12, vjust=0.5, color="black")) +
  theme(axis.text.x =element_text(angle=0, size=12, vjust=0.5, color="black")) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=14))+ 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=14))
```

[image]
I would appreciate your help since I have looked in other forums, and there is information to highlight when there is only 1 line.

Comment: Please add your data frame by copying the output from the function `dput`

Comment: Can you please share enough data to make a minimal reproducible example? Either `dput()` or code to simulate fake data would be perfect, as it will be copy/pasteable.

Comment: And can you explain better what do you mean by "shade the 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles of evary line"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this data is a bit more representative of the data displayed in your plot:

```r
set.seed(50)

QPA_G_Feb17 <- data.frame(density = c(rgamma(400, 2, 10), 
                                      rgamma(400, 2.25, 9),
                                      rgamma(400, 5, 7)),
                          source = rep(c("Algae", "Biofilm", "Leaflitter"), 
                                       each = 400))
```

I find that when you are trying to do something complex or non-standard in `ggplot`, the best thing to do is calculate the data you wish to plot ahead of time. In this case, we can calculate the density curves and the cumulative densities, including their 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles, and putting them all in a data frame like this:

```
dens <- lapply(split(QPA_G_Feb17, QPA_G_Feb17$source), 
               function(x) density(x$density, from = 0, to = 1))

df <- do.call(rbind, mapply(function(x, y) {
                             data.frame(x = x$x, y = x$y, source = y)
                            }, dens, names(dens), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(source) %>%
  mutate(cdf = cumsum(y * mean(diff(x))),
         lower = cdf < 0.025,
         upper = cdf > 0.975)
```

Now it is easy to plot using `geom_area`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = source)) + 
  geom_area(data = df[df$lower,], aes(fill = source), alpha = 0.5,
            position = "identity") +
  geom_area(data = df[df$upper,], aes(fill = source), alpha = 0.5,
            position = "identity") +
  labs(y = "Density", x = "Source contribution") +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = source), size = 1.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#31a354", "#2c7fb8", "#d95f0e")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#31a354", "#2c7fb8", "#d95f0e")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dotted", "longdash")) +
  theme_classic() +
  ylim(0, 5) +
  xlim(0, 1) +
  theme(axis.text.y  = element_text(size = 12, vjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x  = element_text(size = 12, vjust = 0.5),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14))
```

[image]

Here, the 2.5% and 97.5% extremeties of each density curve are shaded below each line. The exception is in the "Leaflitter` line, which clearly extends out of the 0-1 range that has been plotted in your example.

Comment: Hi @Allan Cameron.  Thank you for your help with this graph, your solution was great.  I was wondering if you can help me to put the credible intervals (instead of the confidence intervals). The function would be ```hdi()``` from the ```HDInterval``` package.  Thanks in advance.